# Alternative to Easystroke (mouse gesture recognition software)

Tags: software-recommendation, gestures

Even though I really like easystroke's feature set , I would like to know if there is any other gesture recognition software out there, preferably with a larger feature set or more accurate gesture recognition.

A quick google search brought gestikk to my attention , has anyone used it and want to share his/her experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried gestikk out in the past, but easystroke really had much, much more features and a better user interface. I also looked for an alternative, but I couldn't find any that had at least half amount of easystrokes' features. Anyway, I'm completely satisfied with easystroke and >60 defined gestures ^^

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i'll stay with easystroke then

Answer (score 0):

easystroke can do anything the imagination has a desire for. I has scrybe like feature where you can google a word

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1836089

Set the tap zones as any button you like and even control as scroll wheels and set it up so it gives you two finger scrolling and middle click using the touchpad

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1859936

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i already know its feature set - i have been using it since the first time the developer announced it on ubuntu forums some years ago

Answer (score 0):

You can try out GEM (GEstures with Mouse). Check on http://www.cdacmumbai.in/accessibility.