# How to install gestikk on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, gestures

I am very obsessed with mouse gestures, as I am from a Windows background. I have recently switched to Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm loving it, but the fact that I'm not able to run mouse gestures is the only thing that makes me sad. I found somewhere that we can use `gestikk` and I followed the instructions in [this article](https://www.ubuntugeek.com/gestikk-mouse-gesture-recognition-in-ubuntu.html), but unfortunately it gives me this error while installing:

```
*Selecting previously unselected package gestikk.
(Reading database ... 242508 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack gestikk_0.6-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking gestikk (0.6-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gestikk:
 gestikk depends on python (>= 2.5); however:
  Package python is not installed.
 gestikk depends on python-gtk2 (>= 2.12); however:
  Package python-gtk2 is not installed.
 gestikk depends on python-glade2; however:
  Package python-glade2 is not installed.
 gestikk depends on python-notify; however:
  Package python-notify is not installed.
 gestikk depends on python-virtkey; however:
  Package python-virtkey is not installed.
 gestikk depends on python-kiwi; however:
  Package python-kiwi is not installed.
 gestikk depends on python-pyparsing (>= 1.4.7); however:
  Package python-pyparsing is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package gestikk (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gestikk*
```

Then I tried running this command:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

but it removes `gestikk` and displays the following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gestikk
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 371 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 242540 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing gestikk (0.6-0ubuntu1) ...
```

How to install `gestikk` on Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: I don't know about you, but mouse gestures work perfectly fine on my laptop. Please try including logs and error code to get your answer quicker.

Comment: Try follow this [article](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) when you post next time @Raghav, Okay ;) ?

Comment: @Rishon_JR, can you please help me to get it, it will be very appreciate if you can share steps to install and use any mouse gesture application. Thanks1

Comment: It seems Gestik requires python2. This version is no longer supported, which seems to be the underlying problem.

Comment: @Rishon_JR Do you perhaps mean *touchpad gestures*? Because AFAIK *mouse gestures* aren't supported on Ubuntu (GNOME) by default (not sure if some third-party software exists, thus I'm also interested in this question).

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog Oh yeah sorry… I meant touchpad gestures

Comment: @Raghav try this and see if this works: https://askubuntu.com/questions/51787/alternative-to-easystroke-mouse-gesture-recognition-software

Comment: Install `touchegg` and `touche` (requires flatpak). See https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/06/multi-touch-gestures-ubuntu-20-04/

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: Sorry for the bold comparison and bad news in this answer.*

The [article you link to](https://www.ubuntugeek.com/gestikk-mouse-gesture-recognition-in-ubuntu.html) is from 2008. In IT terms this is mostly equivalent to an archeological dig - i.e. it's *very old*.

This also matches with the project's [Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/gestikk), which was last updated in June 2008. So it's safe to say the project is now abandoned.

As a consequence, the application uses Python 2 which was [discontinued entirely](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) on January 1, 2020.

Apart from the outdated version of Python, an application this old could very well have other problems as well with unforeseen consequences.

While the article was probably correct (we actually don't know) in 2008, it's safe to say it's not anymore.

So either, the application should be updated to use Python 3, or you should probably look for other options.

Comment: You could include something called as “easystroke”

Comment: @Rishon_JR if you mean [this](http://easystroke.sourceforge.net/), it seems unmaintained as well (even the "actively maintained fork" hasn't been updated for several years). However, if you like, you can add an answer. But I wouldn't personally recommend unmaintained applications.

Answer (score 1):

### Alternatives to gestikk

- [Easystroke](http://easystroke.sourceforge.net/) (Not recommended as it's not maintained)
- [Easygesture](https://github.com/bjbr-dev/easy-gesture) (Actively maintained fork of easystroke)

I'm not sure if this works 100% as I don't have Ubuntu running at the time of writing this answer.

As Artur Meinild said, Gestikk uses python2 instead of python3. `apt` removes anything which has outdated libraries while force installing.
Unmaintained software is not recommended as it can have security issues.